# Finding the Equations of Motion for the Leapfrog Integrator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, simulation

I understand that the Leapfrog Integrator is used to find an integral for Newton's Laws of Motion and that the Equation of Motion are given by:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = v$$ and $$\frac{dv}{dt} = F(x) = -\frac{dU(x)}{dx}$$

where $U(x)$ is the Potential Energy at $x$ and $F(x)$ is the force on the particle at $x$. The Leapfrog Integrator itself is:

$$x_{k + \frac{1}{2}} = x_{k} + \frac{h}{2}p_{k}$$

$$p_{k + 1} = p_{k} + hf(x_{k + \frac{1}{2}}, t + \frac{h}{2})$$

$$x_{k + 1} = x_{k + \frac{1}{2}} + \frac{h}{2}p_{k + \frac{1}{2}}$$

How would you go about finding the Equations of Motion for two particles with co-ordinates $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ that are connected by a string and move in two dimensions with a Potential Energy given by:

$$U(x_{1}, x_{2}) = |x_{1} - x_{2}| + |x_{1}|^4 + 3|x_{2}|^4$$

What would be the Equations of Motion be in this case? Also how do they fit into the Leapfrog Integrator provided?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you define the Hamiltonian of the system, which corresponds to
the total energy, that is, kinetic energy plus potential energy. In
your case it reads

$H(p,q) = \frac{p^2}{2} + U(q)$,

where $p$ is the momentum and $q=\binom{x_1}{x_2}$ is the position (note that $p$ and $q$ are vectors). Then,
you derive the equation of motion by computing

$\dot{p} = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial q},\quad 
\dot{q} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}$

(it could be useful to replace the absolute value $\vert x \vert$ by $\sqrt{(x)^2}$).

In this case you obtain

$\dot{q} = p, \quad 
\dot{p} = \frac{1}{\Vert q \Vert}q + \binom{4q_1^3}{12q_2^3} = f(q)$

Finally, you invoke the Leapfrog scheme, which reads

$$p_{k+1/2} = p_k + \frac{h}{2}f(q_k),$$
$$q_{k+1} = q_k + hp_{k+1/2},$$
$$p_{k+1} = p_{k+1/2} + \frac{h}{2}f(q_{k+1}).$$